# Javascript Regex Issue Turkish Character

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I am trying to add searching feature to my list pages. I implement search function on client side with javascript. But I have a problem with only one turkish character "İ". It doesn't work case insensitive search with regex. For example `^(?=.*?ŞAHİN).*$/i` expression can not find "şahin" or vice versa. Other turkish characters work properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `RegExp` constructor?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What encoding your pages have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?=.*?ŞAH[İi]N).*$/i
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it should work...